# Is the comma being appropriately used to distinguish between these meanings

Tags: grammaticality

And is there a term for when you put a comma right after a noun, followed by the command (verb phrase)?

"Soldiers, march."

A imperative statement telling the soldiers to march.

"Soldiers march."

A declarative statement about an action soldiers perform.

Comment: Answered here: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/281085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is in **Vocative Case.** The soldiers are being addressed. The second one is just stating a fact. See the difference between the following examples: *People, don't listen to that monster. People don't listen to that monster.*