# In a sentence "What's up, my friends?" should I put a comma between "what's up" and "friends"?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, british-english

In a sentence "What's up, my friends?" and "Hey, everyone!" should I put a comma between "What's up" and "friends" and "Hey" and "everyone" respectively? Is there a particular set of rules?

Comment: Certainly it makes a difference if one is asking, "What's up, Edward II?"

Answer (score 0):

When a person/persons are addressed directly in a sentence, the nouns so used, proper or common, are called [nouns of direct address](http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/nouns_of_direct_address_examples/59/). The second person pronoun, "you," can also be used to address someone directly, as can the indefinite pronouns "everyone" or "everybody." Nouns/pronouns of direct address are always set off by commas, regardless of where they fall in the sentence.

> And that, my friends, is what is wrong with Congress today.
>
> It's time to eat, Grandma! (Try this sentence *without* the comma!)
>
> John, your taxi is waiting.
>
> Look, you, don't try that again unless you want the toaster to blow up in your face.
>
> Hey, everyone, Maryanne's brought a chocolate cake.

Comment: This has been covered on ELU before. Though the 'vocative comma' is often necessary for disambiguation, it is rapidly becoming seen as an optional pause-marker in say << "Hello, world!" / "Hello world!" >>

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281085/is-vocative-comma-rule-vanishing

Comment: You didn't bother to stick a couple of your "optional pause-markers" around a parenthetical "say" in your comment, but that doesn't *yet* make the usage the rule. There is a certain logic in not sticking a comma in the middle of a very short sentence like "Welcome new students," but it's another matter assuming this is a new paradigm and extending it to potentially edible grandparents.