# Is it necessary to use a vocative comma in an email, specifically a professional email?

Tags: commas, email, vocatives

I received an email this morning from a candidate for an Executive Director position.

Thanks Kim.

This is how the email began. It immediately made a negative impression and caused me to feel this individual does not possess the writing skills I believe are essential for the position. It also could be a sign that she does not pay attention to details.  She was the number one candidate for the position.  I do not feel the same after receiving this email.  My husband, however, began an intense discussion regarding the use of the comma in such a sentence.  He believes it to be unnecessary, and possibly incorrect to include a comma.  He does not feel it should have an impact on my decision. Times are changing.  I still prefer 2 spaces between sentences!  The fact the applicant is over 60 adds some support to my concern regarding her eye for details.  Should this impact my decision?

Comment: Can't see the problem.

Comment: You have two questions. To answer the main one: yes, the applicant should have used the comma. An answer that will support your contention is at: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/281106/3306.  To answer your second question ("Should this impact my decision") will engage a lot of heat because there are a lot of opinions, and may be beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: *It immediately made a negative impression and caused me to feel this individual does not possess the writing skills* One wonders the degree to which your belief in a conservative style is hindering the best decision for the company.